# How to build a Gmap that zooms by getting hashtags from twitter?

Tags: php, google-maps, twitter, hashtag

So I am working on a little experiment thing combining the Google maps API and the Twitter API. What I want to achieve is start a little promotion action, by letting people tweet about my event with the hastag: 'GoFlyRotterdam'. On my Google map there is a marker that points out a prize. Every time someone posts a tweet with 'GoFlyRotterdam', the Google map has to zoom in a little bit on the prize. Eventually when people get the hang of it and start tweeting about it in a massive proportion, the map gets clearer and clearer about the specific location of the prize. The first one that gets there get the prize.
I also have to hide the latitude and longitude for the cheaters among the users! 
My question to you all is:

**'what's the best solution on building this thing?' how would you building something like this in steps?'**

This is how far I am so far:

- I'm using the static images API from Gmaps so people can not zoom in.
- I'm using a hashtag counter and used some 'if' statements to zoom in  the map if a hashtag is above a certain number. But loading all the hashtags on refresh takes too damn long (how to solve this??!?!?!)

inspiration: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CSYxDz22DqY

building languages: php, javascript

Comment: One solution is to, instead of doing the re-calculation, If the twitter api has the ability to "postback" if there is a new tweet with that hastag you could register to that postback and update your data then, the other option is to instead run the update on a cron, so that your data is updated every say 15 minutes...

Comment: Alright, thanks. Another question I have is if I can use the Google maps zoom variable like '5.004'. I tried, but it doesn't work. But I need the zoomlevel to be more specific with decimals. How to achieve this?